# Breaks span in drag & drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tell me please. If you drag a span specifically to another span and not to a free space, some kind of merging occurs (see gif).
How to fix this error?
Thank you in advance.
[image]

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop {
width:100px;
height:50px;
display:block;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:#fafafa;width:100%;height:440px;padding-top:10px;">
  <div style="text-align:center;width:49%;height: 100%;display:inline-block;border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span class="drop" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-orderID="1">SPAN 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;width:49%;height: 100%;display:inline-block;">
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span class="drop" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2"  data-orderID="2">SPAN 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you like to happen?

Comment: The "merging" is that it goes inside the other span. You would like to prevent it being dropped in that span?

Comment: Just use min-height instead of height, if the error is that the span does not grow.  If not, please clarify what the actual error is as it's not very clear

Comment: @j08691 The problem pointed to the gif animation. When we move a span to a span, the two spans merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the drop inside the span, you can prevent the drop from that node. `<span class="drop" ondrop="event.stopPropagation();"` That makes sure your handler on the containing div doesn't get called.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop {
width:100px;
height:50px;
display:block;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:#fafafa;width:100%;height:440px;padding-top:10px;">
  <div style="text-align:center;width:49%;height: 100%;display:inline-block;border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span class="drop" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" data-orderID="1">SPAN 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;width:49%;height: 100%;display:inline-block;">
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <span class="drop" ondrop="event.stopPropagation();" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2"  data-orderID="2">SPAN 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This prevents the merging of spans the user requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your drop event is triggered on the `span` not on the containing `div`.
So the dragged element is appended to the span it's dragged onto.

You can prevent this by altering the line

`ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`
to 
`ev.target.closest('div').appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`